# Heavy CPU load VmWare Fusion (8) process with Windows 10 Enterprise and Visual Studio Pro 2015

Tags: windows-10, cpu, vmware-fusion, osx-el-capitan, visual-studio-2015

I've started to notice when running my VM (unity mode) the Activity Manager shows a rather big CPU load for the VmWare process. Let's say I would be using 20% of my CPU but the process itself would show up to 450% CPU load.

The standard load with just Win 10 and VS 2015 with ReSharper running (idle) would be around 150% (about 10-15% in the OS X activity monitor). Now as soon as I start running a web application & some services this shot up to the previously mentioned 450%, this happens regularly and I notice responsiveness is not optimal most of the time.

After some googling I disabled the windows update service as this has helped for some before (not specifically Windows 10 but was worth a try). However this didn't give the desired results.

I currently gave my VM: 2 cores, 8gb ram, Intel VT-x/EPT enabled, share internet with Mac. I've tried 4 cores before but that didn't seem to change much either. Note this isn't a bootcamp partition, just a VM from scratch.

Running this on a MacBook Pro Retina 15" Mid 2015

- Intel Core i7 2.5 GHz
- 16 Gb RAM
- 512 GB SSD
- AMD Radeon R9 M370X

Is there anyone with the same experiences or any suggestions to improve the responsiveness and speed?

Comment: does the problem persist with the regular mode?

Comment: Disabling the VT-x/EPT option seemed to have increased the speed a lot.

Answer (score 0):

These .vmx parameters are commonly used for solving VMware performance issues :

```
MemTrimRate = "0"
mainMem.useNamedFile = "FALSE"
mainMem.backing = "swap"
sched.mem.pshare.enable = "FALSE"
MemAllowAutoScaleDown = "FALSE"
prefvmx.useRecommendedLockedMemSize = "TRUE"
```

Not all of them might be required in your case (or they might not be enough),
but you could try and see. I do not believe I have ever tried *all* of them
for one VM, so be careful when introducing them into the .vmx file.

Do not forget to take a backup of the .vmx file before editing it,
and check whether these parameters are already set to other values in the file.